# Essential supremum of function in real line

Tags: measure-theory, supremum-and-infimum

If the pre-image of the function is whole real line and is defined as following:
\begin{equation}
  f(x) =
    \begin{cases}
      1 & \text{if}\,x\in\mathbb{Z} \\
      0 & \text{otherwise}
    \end{cases}       
\end{equation}

What would be the essential supremum?

I understand that the essential supremum of a function is the smallest value that is larger or equal than the function values almost everywhere when allowing for ignoring what the function does at a set of points of measure zero.

Would it be still zero considering each individual integer essentially has measure zero? However, the measure of the integer set with value 1 is not zero, is it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The measure of $\mathbb Z$ is $0$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy That makes sense considering union of sets of measure zero is still zero. In that case, the essential supremum would be 0. Right?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, indeed the essential supremum of this function is zero given the fact that union of sets of measure zero is still zero.